# How do I do this pryrmiad on the top of rectangular container in expressing the cost as a function of widith?

Tags: functions, optimization

This was the example that teacher gave us. A rectangular storage container with an open top is to have a volume of 10 m3. The length of this base is twice the width. Material for the base costs $\$15$ per square meter. Material for the sides costs $\$10$ per square meter. Find the cost of materials for the cheapest such container.

I solved finding first constrain equation which is $v=lwh= 5=w^2 h$.

And the the objective minimisation cost, which is $\text{cost}=(\text{area})(\text{price per }m^2)$.

Which is $36wh + 20w^2$, combing both equations I found $c= \frac{180}{w} +20w^2$.

Now he asked us and says the pyramid on the top of that rectangular container and express the cost as a function of the width of the container's shortest side.

The pyramid also has same height as the container.

The cost of the each sides of the pyramid is $18$ per meter square.

Total volume and all other informations are the same with the class example.

Please help me how do I found total volume in these two different situations. I’m really so confused. Thank you

Comment: $v=lwh=5=w^2h$ is not true.  You are using $l=2w$ and the first and third $=$ signs are correct, but $v=10$ is given.  Please be more careful.  I don't see where your cost equation comes from.  The cost of the  base is $15wl=30w^2$.  The perimeter of the base is $6w$ so the cost of the sides is $6wh\cdot 10=60wh$  The volume of a pyramid is $\frac 13Ah$, where $A$ is the area of the base, here $2w^2$.  You don't need the volume of the pyramid, you need the area of its sides, which are all triangles.

Comment: Do I need to solve the slant height too, to find the area, I’m kind confused sorry.

Comment: The question I’m interested is The one he says put the pyramid on the top of that rectangular container and express the cost as a function of the width of the container's shortest side.

The pyramid also has same height as the container.

The cost of the each sides of the pyramid is 18
 per meter square.

Comment: Dear @RossMillikan is this way corrct